# How to theme a form with bootstrap

Tags: 7, theming

I want to add much HTML to my form elements in order to arrange them on the page, I will be using bootstrap framework to do this.

Which method would be better, to create a twig template file or to use HOOK_form_alter?

If the way to do this would be to create a twig template file, then how can I ensure the form html tags with the form method is also rendered to the page? I have attempted to do this but I don't know how to get the actual form to render, just the inputs are there in the html source code.

I know in Drupal 7 that you had to render something called child elements, but when I check for this array in Kint there is no such thing.

Answer (score 1):

A good starting point is the [bootstrap theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap). They have a stable version for drupal 8. (It's the most object oriented theme I've seen so far)

> So I would suggest to make your custom theme, as sub-theme of it.

If you want to do it fully by yourself, you would use hook_form alter existing forms (if needed) and theme_hooks/html.twig to add some bootstrap specific classes and change HTML structure.
The mentioned theme is a good starting point to look at all the things that need to be changed.

Comment: Ok thanks, so I will use Hook_form_alter to add classes to the already existing html? Can this be done in the MYTHEME.theme file?

Comment: I really would suggest you use the bootstrap theme. (or at least check out their code for reuse)

hook_form_(FORM_ID)_alter is normally used in a custom module to alter existing form.
theme_hook (like theme_checkbox) is normally placed in the .theme file you mentioned, and is the way also to add classes and change the HTML structure for all those elements.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.hbensalem.com/php/drupal-7-and-bootstrap-3-theming-the-login-form/

That gives some code to add to the template.php file for a login form and could be a useful base for you to improve upon.

I'm doing the exact same thing as you are right now.